# Ordem das variáveis locais no stack frame

Tags: c, linux, gerenciamento-de-memória, gcc, runtime

Existe maneira fácil em C de visualizar (imprimir) o *stack frame* atual (ou a área de dados, que é a parte da espaço de memória que parece que o código abaixo está)? Para aprendizado. Estava brincando com arrays e fiquei curioso.

Pesquisando sobre o assunto parece que não existe garantia de ordem, é uma decisão que é postergada para o passo da montagem, e pode variar conforme *flags* passadas ao compilador. Confere essa informação?

No caso estou usando `gcc` no Linux 64 bits.

Eu tentei declarar umas variáveis locais e imprimir seus endereços para tentar visualizar, mas fiquei com mais dúvidas ainda.

Vou colocar um código de exemplo para a pergunta não ficar muito abstrata.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char x = 150;
  char arr[1];
  char y = 180;
  char *arrptr = NULL;

  arrptr = (char *)malloc(1);

  arr[0] = 65;
  arrptr[0] = arr[0];
  printf("%d ", arr[0]);
  printf("\n");
  
  arrptr[0] = '\0';

  arr[0] = 5;

  printf("&x\t\t%ld\n", (long int)&x);
  printf("arr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)arr);
  printf("&arr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)&arr);
  printf("&(arr[0])\t%ld\n", (long int)&(arr[0]));
  printf("arr[0]\t\t%d\n", arr[0]);
  printf("&y\t\t%ld\n", (long int)&y);
  printf("&arrptr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)&arrptr);
  printf("arrptr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)arrptr);
  printf("&arrptr[0]\t%ld\n", (long int)&arrptr[0]);
}
```

**Saída:**

```
65 
&x          140724452912758
arr         140724452912775
&arr        140724452912775
&(arr[0])   140724452912775
arr[0]      5
&y          140724452912759
&arrptr     140724452912760
arrptr      94104105513632
&arrptr[0]  94104105513632
```

O endereço de `arrptr[0]` mostrado ao final está bonitinho lá no *heap*, afastado dos demais endereços que estão no stack, isso eu consegui visualizar.

Os endereços de `x` e `y` estão adjacentes, o que me intriga duas vezes: pois cada endereço deveria ocupar 8 bytes (não devendo os finais de cada um portanto ser adjacentes) e por `x` e `y` não estarem declaradas adjacentes no código. **EDIT:** Na verdade a explicação da primeira dúvida é que é a posição de valores `char` e não de ponteiros (endereços de 8 bytes), me confundi.

Também não consegui com base nesses valores estabelecer uma lógica do tipo "esses oito bytes guardam o endereço da variável `bla` e ficam a um *offset* de tantos bytes da outra variável `ble`".

Comment: Não. Respondido?

Comment: É meio frustrante que não tenha,  seria legal poder visualizar. Mas ok, obrigado :)

Comment: Use o debugger. Vai aprender mais. E imprima o mapa do linker usando `--print-map`  No debugger pode ver o layout completo da memória usando os endereços de base com o programa já rodando. O mapa do linker vai te dar alguns deslocamentos importantes